# Where to make http request for every route in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Suppose my web app needs to make a http request to get my site title, site description and so on. Since these variables are common to all pages, it makes sense to request those every time a user enter the site.

The question is, where do I make those calls? In run block? Or to create a root controller to do these tasks?

Comment: I think, you can use root ( or main ) controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of these two approaches:

1. Make your call in run block and store the value in `$rootScope` and
   use anywhere you want,
2. In your states, use `resolve` to get the page title and details , and
   get it in the views , For ease use resolve in root state and use the
   resolved variable as a dependency in other child or sibling  routes
   to get values..

   ```
       $stateProvider.state('root', {
         resolve:{

           // Example using function with simple return value.        
           promiseObj:  function($http){
           // $http returns a promise for the url data
           return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'});
         }
       })
      .state('sibling',{
        controller:function($scope,promiseObj){
         $scope.title = promiseObj.title;
        }
       })
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could define controller at the `<html>` level.

```
 <html ng-app="app" ng-controller="initCtrl">
   <head>
     <title>{{ Page.title() }}</title>
 ...
```

You create service: `Page` and modify from controllers.

```
myModule.factory('Page', function() {
   var title = //Code to get the title
   .... //Other vars
   return {
     title: function() { return title; },
     setTitle: function(newTitle) { title = newTitle }
     ...
   };
});
```

Inject Page and Call `'Page.setTitle()'` from controllers.